# Problema com Carousel Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-3

Estou usando um carousel bootstrap e os slides não estão passando sozinho.

Esse é o erro que aparece:

> Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'carousel', required by directive 'slide', can't be found!

#### Carousel

```
<div id="box-conteudo" class="clearfix">
  <div id="Box_cont_adj" class="clearfix">
    <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="2000">

      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>


      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="Home/images/banner_1.png" width="965" height="280" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            ...
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="Home/images/banner_2.png" width="965" height="280" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            ...
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="Home/images/banner_3.png" width="965" height="280" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            ...
          </div>
        </div>


        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Você tá usando AngularJS? Se sim, use [ngNonBindable](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngNonBindable) nas tags que carregam os atributos data-slide="prev" e datta-slide="next" e, por favor, edite sua pergunta. Se refira também a [este artigo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26332202/using-ui-bootstrap-causing-issues-with-carousel) do SOF em Inglês

Answer (score -1):

Existe um parâmetro para o `carousel` que você deve definir para que ele dê um `autoplay`, no caso o `interval`:

```
$(function(){
    $('.carousel').carousel({
      interval: 2000
    });
});
```

Se isso não for suficiente, o que deve ser, force a primeira troca:

```
$(function(){
    $('.carousel').carousel({
      interval: 2000
    });
    $('.carousel-control.right').trigger('click');
});
```